# Running executable without specifying a file extension in bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Yesterday when I want to build my project i typed in `./build.sh` and then `./game.out` into my bash terminal on linux to build and respectevly run my game.
But I recently discovered this little code snippet:

```bash
command_not_found_handle() {
    if [[ -x "./$1" ]]; then
        "./$1" "${@:2}"
    else
        echo "Error: Command '$1' not found."
        return 1
    fi
}
```

That lets me run the command without the `./`, so I just type, `build.sh` and `game.out`. This feels like a huge time saver, but I was just wondering if there was any possibility of coding it so that I could just type in `build` and `game`, like in the DOS days, and if so, how?
Yes I've tried googling it, but to no avail, I don't possibly know how to search this paragraph in just a few words.

Comment: add an alias, https://askubuntu.com/questions/154640/how-to-add-an-alias-to-a-command-in-terminal, or place a shebang at the top of the build.sh file, remove the extension and make it executable

Comment: What you're describing would be unusual behavior in the linux world.    Unlike in old DOS filesystems with their "8.3" filename storage space,  file all modern linux filesystems do not have an extension per se, just file names.  Your files' names just ends in `.sh` and `.out`. If you don't want those components in your files, simply rename them.

Comment: Despite the convenience, there is a security reason for generally wanting to prefix command invocation with `./`. If commands in `.` are executed automatically, then a mischievous user can create trojan commands.

Comment: FWIW, `.` `/` `b` **TAB** is less typing than `build`

Comment: As already said, there are security reasons not to do what you are proposing. But if you insist on doing that, it would be easier to modify `$PATH` (and rename the files to the names you desire) rather than use a function for that.

Comment: *huge timesaver*?:D It probably takes me 300ms to type `./`, to save lots of time I'd have to type `./build.sh` thousands of times a day - and, quite frankly, if I did that I'd seriously consider writing some automation around it. :D

Comment: See [Should I save my scripts with the .sh extension?](https://askubuntu.com/q/503127) and [Erlkonig: Commandname Extensions Considered Harmful](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the script path in PATH variable. then no need to enter the absolute or relative address.